# Facebook Application Permissions Error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-permissions

I have a facebook application that require several permissions (i.e. to read user `comments`, `profile picture`, `cover picture` etc). These are set up from the permissions section of my application. The problem is that when users use this application, the only permission access being asked is:

> THIS APP WILL RECEIVE:
>
> Your basic info

Ignoring all the other permissions that I originally required. Any ideas why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Set the list of permissions while logging in the user. For example-

```
FB.login(function(response) 
{
   if (response.authResponse) 
   {
       console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
       FB.api('/me', function(response) 
       {
             console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
       });
   } 
   else 
   {
       console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
},{scope: 'email,user_likes'});
```